# WCF, self signed Certificates for Encryption

Tags: wcf, service, certificate

I want to create WCF services using aspnet membership to authorize the user. However, if  I just need the certificate for encryption purposes only, does it matter if it is a self signed certificate or do you need to buy a certificate from a vendor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use self-signed certificates, but the problem there is that you have to install the certificate on each and every machine that will use the certificate for encryption.

If you have a large number of machines that the clients will run on, this can easily become prohibitive from a maintenance and configuration point of view and it would easily justify the purchase of a certificate from an authority.

Comment: Is there a simple way to expose your public key to the world?

Comment: @user190084: Well, the mechanism in place now is to have it issued by a root authority, which is what I assume you are trying to avoid (for cost reasons, if I assume correctly). You could simply expose it as a link somewhere, but that still leaves it up to the end user to install the certificate on their machine, and that's a trust decision you are asking them to make. With root authorites, it's easier to get them to accept, because *everyone* accepts them, for the most part. Short answer, buy the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

A self-signed certificate regardless of whether you authenticate the user carries the same risks. Best practice is to use a real cert in a production environment. With some very cheap prices these days, it's not much of a financial burden to take on any more either (unless you're a stickler for Verisign).

It's been discussed and noted that self-signed certs in a production WCF environment also come with heavy performance issues:

- [Terrible Performance with WCF and certificates (mutual authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065182/terrible-performance-with-wcf-and-certificates-mutual-authentication)
- http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/08/08/Creating-X509-Certificates-for-WSE-or-WCF.aspx
- http://www.google.com/search?q=wcf+self+signed+performance

Comment: What are the security risk specifically?